# Ansible fails to run a script for a backup of an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, ansible, backup

I use an Ansible-Controller-machine to connect a Server in order to run a script that takes an Oracle database backup and I have the following, for me strange, result:
i)**when I use ssh everything works fine** and I can run a script that makes a database backup
ii)**when I use Ansible, with the same credentials, the script fails**. I found that -although Ansible uses the same user- some env-variables like $PATH, $ORACLE_HOME etc. are different comparing to the connection using ssh. Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the $PATH is missing all the Oracle related directories and the $ORACLE_HOME is empty

Comment: become: yes => root env is set vs become_user: oracle => oracle env is set. Include debug "whoami" msg in your playbook

Comment: Hi Bjarte, the user that I was given does not have root access, but he has enought rights to take a database backup. As I wrote in my initial comment, by using this user I can ssh and make a backup, but using the same user declared in an Ansbile inventory does not work

Answer (score 1):

When you connect with ssh, a profile script is executed and that sets a lot of environment variables.  I don't know anything about Ansible, but it would appear that something about the way it connects does not invoke the profile.  It's the same thing as when a script is run by cron.  Bottom line is all scripts should take care of setting the necessary environment variables for themselves, instead of depending on inheriting them.